# GraphAPIError: (#200) - posting a message as a user to different groups

Tags: python-3.x, facebook

I am trying to post a message as a user in Facebook to different groups (I am not admin in those groups / pages) using the Facebook API (group style: https://www.facebook.com/groups/1643040199240574);

I'm trying the following, and it works for private groups of mine where I am an administrator but not for instance in general for groups I have been accepted to:

```
import facebook

groups = [1428340887415620] 

b_link = True
token = "not displayed"


# Create a Facebook Graph API object

if b_link:
    # Post a message to Facebook
    msg = "Hello guys ! Exciting news! 4 nomad friends and I have been busy building a new app for us digital nomads to meet each other based on our travel plans. The app is called Punta. You just add travel plans and connect with digital nomads who will be in the same places as you on the same dates, allowing you to make meaningful connections before even arriving. We’re thrilled to hear your feedback on the app, as it’s still in its infancy. Your thoughts will help us help you by improving the user experience and exploring new and different features. We want to hear all your opinions. Feel free to write me in a private as well if you have doubts!"
    link = "https://www.punta.app"
    graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=token)

    for group in groups:
        x= graph.put_object(group, connection_name='feed', message=msg, link = link)
    
        print(x)
        print("message sent successfully using python")
```

I get the following mistake:

> GraphAPIError: (#200) If posting to a group, requires app being
> installed in the group, and 
> either publish_to_groups permission with user token, or both pages_read_engagement 
> and pages_manage_posts permission with page token; If posting to a page, 
> requires both pages_read_engagement and pages_manage_posts as an admin with 
> sufficient administrative permission

Can I do it ? is there something I am not understanding ?
This are the permissions I have selected in the graph API:

- user_managed_groups
- groups_show_list
- pages_show_list
- publish_to_groups
- groups_access_member_info
- page_events
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_manage_posts
- pages_manage_engagement

I am using a user_token

Thank you for your time,

Comment: "requires app being installed in the group" - is that the case?

Comment: btw, judging from the message in your code, i would assume that you want to spam groups. don't do that. api restrictions are there for good reasons.

Comment: No there is no way to spam groups.

Comment: okei, I thought that could be possible though.

Comment: hello @andyrandy, I am a member (or user) of those groups, but I am not an administrator. what does it mean `requires app being installed in the group `?

Comment: It means that a group admin needs to install the app in the group. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/overview#app-installation